# firebase realtime database rules to allow multiple uid for write access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to allow only 2 specific uid for write access and I can't publish with my current rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === 'abc123' || '123abc'",
    }
}
```

It keeps complain "rule regulation may not contain '|' operator" and
"right operand for '||' must be boolean", which ever i used.
How should I change my rule to achieve what I want?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word after || is actually not a boolean, it is just a string. Please, check my fixed code.

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null && (auth.uid === 'abc123' || auth.uid === '123abc')",
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. However, I found that i have set the wrong rules. I will still mark this as answer for my question though. Appreciate your help.